# Integrating Angular External IP with ClusterIP of .NET microservices on AKS

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster where I've deployed both Angular frontend applications and .NET microservices. The Angular frontend applications are exposed externally using LoadBalancer services, which provide an External IP.

Now, I want to communicate from the Angular frontend to the .NET microservices using their internal ClusterIPs. However, I'm encountering issues with DNS resolution or connectivity when trying to use the ClusterIPs within the Angular application.

I've tried accessing the .NET microservices using their ClusterIPs (http://servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local), but it doesn't seem to work. However, I can access the microservices externally using their LoadBalancer IPs.

Here are some details:

- Angular frontend service: myangularappservice with External IP 13.xx.xx.6
- .NET microservices service: nonkpusermngprod with ClusterIP 10.0.31.38

Could someone guide me on how to properly configure DNS resolution or network connectivity so that my Angular frontend can communicate with the .NET microservices using their ClusterIPs?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!